# how my friend can connect his laptop to mine via wireless connection to using internet

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, internet-connection

actually I don't want to pass my ssid & password of my broadband to him,but I want he use internet through my laptop via wireless.
cheers

Comment: If you are connected via your wireless card to your wifi access point, it's impossible.

Comment: mine is connected through cable

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean an ad-hoc wireless network.

[Directions for Windows.](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx)

[Directions for OSX.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network-between-macs.html)

[Directions for Linux.](http://www.atlink.it/~conti/articles/creating-an-ad-hoc-wireless-connection-with-linux/)

Comment: nope,connection is supposed to be established via wireless card

Comment: Can you give us some info on what kind of laptops you have here?  And what do you mean, all these options are for wireless connections between computers.

Comment: that s so simple,
I am connected to internet via cable,my friend wants to use internet,but I wanna he uses my laptop as Base;in other words he get connected to internet via wireless

Comment: All these directions will accomplish what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Like @netme commented, you can't use the same network interface to connect to the internet and share it at the same time. If you're connected to the internet through something different, like wired ethernet, you can then create an ad-hoc wireless network, use your computer as a router, and share that to your friend.

For your situation, I would recommend just changing your Wi-Fi ssid+pass, at least temporarily, to something you wouldn't mind him having access to.

Comment: can you explain more for the first option